# Python - average of non-negative integers in any list

Tags: python

Python newbie here, second week.  The goal here is to write a program that would find the average of the non-negative values of any list, not just the one provided.

```
numbers = [11.5, 28.3, 23.5, -4.8, 15.9, -63.1, 79.4, 80.0, 0, 67.4, -11.9, 32.6]
average = 0

# write your code here so that it sets average
# to the average of the non-negative numbers

num = list(numbers)
avg = sum(num (num >= 0)) / len(num)
average == avg

print(average)
return average
```

Output :
Error on line 10:
for n in range(num)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Another version I could compile :

```
numbers = [11.5, 28.3, 23.5, -4.8, 15.9, -63.1, 79.4, 80.0, 0, 67.4, -11.9, 32.6]
average = 0

num = int.input(numbers (numbers >= 0))
for n in range(num)
    positive_integers = float(input(numbers))
    total += positive_integers

average = total / length(num)

print(average)
return average
```

Output :
Error on line 9:
for n in range(numbers)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can you help me understand this? Thanks!

Comment: ```return``` to be used only inside a function, also, ```sum(num (num >= 0))``` is wrong, you can do,```list2=[x for x in numbers if x>=0]```, ```sum(list2)/len(list2)```

Answer (score 1):

Beginner Friendly Solution :

```
numbers = [11.5, 28.3, 23.5, -4.8, 15.9, -63.1, 79.4, 80.0, 0, 67.4, -11.9, 32.6]
total_sum = 0
number_of_elements = 0

for number in numbers:
    if number >= 0:
       total_sum += number # sum of all the non negative elements
       number_of_elements += 1 # count of non-negative elements in the list

average = total_sum / number_of_elements
print(average)
```

The Error You mentioned tells that you are comparing list `num` with a int `0` which is not correct

This is an invalid statement in Python

> sum(num (num >= 0))

Comment: this is brilliant, I can think of this in my head but I'm finding it difficult to compile the code. looking at the solution it seems so simple now, I guess its part of the learning process! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do. Also, it you want to round of the average, you can simply use `round(average,<num>) #==== Whatever number you want in <num>`

```
numbers = [11.5, 28.3, 23.5, -4.8, 15.9, -63.1, 79.4, 80.0, 0, 67.4, -11.9, 32.6]
non_negative=[num for num in numbers if num>=0] #==== List comprehension which iterates over the numbers list and contains only those elements if condition num>=0 is met
average=sum(non_negative)/len(non_negative) #=== Sum is the sum of all elements in the list, len is the number of elements of the lists
print("Average is: ",average)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are specific performance reasons, like you’re dealing with hundreds of millions of numbers and are closing to running out of RAM, I like to optimize for readability. How would a mathematician describe the solution? They’d say something like:

- Find all of the non-negative numbers.
- Divide the sum of that list by the length of the list.

OK, let’s do that then!

```py
numbers = [11.5, 28.3, 23.5, -4.8, 15.9, -63.1, 79.4, 80.0, 0, 67.4, -11.9, 32.6]
average = 0

# Built a list of all of the non-negative numbers
non_negatives = [num for num in numbers if num >= 0]

# This should look familar
average = sum(non_negatives) / len(non_negatives)

print(average)
```

First, this is going to run about as fast as you could possibly make it run, as the C Python interpreter is doing all the heavy lifting, not your own code. Second, each line of this is going to make sense when you come back six months later and try to remember what you *intended* to do.

In general, make your Python code as readable as possible first. Don’t try to make it “clever” or “fast” until you *know* that you need it.